# mysql with java on linux threading

Tags: java, linux, web-services, class, java-threads

Im doing a project that will be running on a ubuntu server. Im writing this on windows using Eclipse IDE. The need of the program is to have 1 main class and another class (called Proxy) to be used inside the main class. the way im going to be running this is by having a cron job that will execute "java myProgram" every determined time.

My program will be accessing a webservice and dumping some info on a mysql DB, i've been told that i should use threads so that the system will not stall, is this only for the Mysql connection or the SOAP call should use it too?

General speaking the program will do 4 calls to a webservice, proccess the data being retrieved from it and then dump the proccessed info into the DB. That's why the program will be called every x mins.

Eg. if the program was to be executed every 30 mins, the program would run and grab information from the webservice from the last 30 mins and dump it. and the cron job would take care to execute the next time in 30 mins.

Comment: 1) When you have many classes, use packages to organize the code (topic too broad for full description). --- 2) Deploy runnable code using Jar file. --- 3) Too broad/unspecific to answer.

Comment: thanks and sorry, i have edited the question